# BMR calculator not giving me answer that I want (If else issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, calculator

I'm making a BMR calculator right now and I have most of the stuff already in mind. For some reason this code doesn't want to give me the right values with `if` `else`. It gives me only one of the conditions even if it's the other (ex. calculates for female if male).

```js
var bmr = 0;


function calc() {
  var age = document.getElementById("age").value;
  var gender = document.getElementById("gender").value;
  var height = document.getElementById("height").value;
  var weight = document.getElementById("weigth").value;

  if (gender == 'male') {
    bmr = 447.593 + (9.247 * weight) + (3.098 * height) - (4.330 * age);
  } else if (gender == 'female') {

    bmr = 88.362 + (13.397 * weight) + (4.799 * height) - (5.677 * age);
  }
}



document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0].addEventListener("click", function() {
  calc();
  document.getElementById('lblResult').innerHTML = bmr;

})
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
  background-color: #19a4fa;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

header {
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #0051ffee, #ff00d4);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: auto 100%;
  padding: .5em 0 .5em 5.5em;
  height: fit-content;
  text-align: center;
}

#wrapper {
  width: 980px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

#grad1 {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: red;
  /* For browsers that do not support gradients */
  background-image: linear-gradient(155deg, #19a4fa, #a527f8);
}

#centre {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="grad1">
  <div id="wrapper">
    <header>

      <h1>BMR Calculator</h1>

    </header>
    <br>
    <h4><strong>What is BMR?:</strong></h4>
    <p>Basal Metabolic Rate (BMR) is your metabolism rate. It calculates the total amount of calories you should be eating per day based on Age, Height, Weight, and Gender.</p>

    <div id="centre">
      <form action="#">

        <label for="gender">Gender:</label><br>
        <input type="radio" id="gender" name="gender" value="male" required="required"> Male
        <input type="radio" id="gender" name="gender" value="female" required="required"> Female<br><br>

        <label for="age">How old are you?</label><br>
        <input type="number" id="age" value="age" required="required"><br><br>

        <label for="height">What is your height in centimetres? (cm):</label><br>
        <input type="number" id="height" value="height" required="required"><br><br>

        <label for="gender">What is your wight in kilograms? (kg):</label><br>
        <input type="number" id="weigth" value="weight" required="required"><br><br>
      </form>


      <button type="button" onclick="">
      Result</button><br>

      <textarea id="lblResult">BMR</textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This was bugging me for a while, would really appreciate some assistance.

Comment: `} else if {` is incorrect. It should be just `} else {`. However in your case a switch statment would be more appropiate

Comment: Interestingly, in javascript a switch statement performs just about as well as ifelse. Also his if else is not wrong, but you are correct in that else would be the logical option, since there are only two possible choices.

Comment: Im trying to add more to this, so I thought its best to add a switch with a nested if statement, but now it is only going to whats in the default, and not when the other conditions are active

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In html/javascript you should make sure IDs are unique. In the following:

```
 <input type="radio" id="gender" name="gender" value="male" required="required"> Male
 <input type="radio" id="gender" name="gender" value="female" required="required"> Female<br><br>
```

You have assigned the `ID` of gender to both input elements.

Now to fix the gender selection, what you need to do is create a selector that only fetches the currently selected radio button.

```
var gender = document.querySelector('input[name="gender"]:checked').value;
```

Comment: I CANT BELIEVE IT WAS THIS EASY. I cant thank you enough

Comment: @Laser_ You can't believe how often that happens to us all =). Glad I could help!